# How should i display chat messages on left side and right side in the terms of designing

Tags: php, mysql

The error is in line number 12 `if($display["logged_user"]==$user)`. Error is

> Notice: Undefined index: logged_user

If I use `=` instead to `==` to compare the value it displays all the chat messages between two users in one side only. I want to display the logged user messages in left side and friend messages in right side.Thanks in advance.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'company');
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select `message` FROM `data` where 
            (`logged_user`='$_SESSION[ID]' and `name`='$_SESSION[frendid]') 
            OR 
            (`logged_user`='$_SESSION[frendid]' and `name`='$_SESSION[ID]')");
    $user=$_SESSION['ID'];
    $rows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($rows>0) {
            while($display=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            if($display["logged_user"]==$user){ 
                echo "<p id ='right'>
                    $display[message]
                    </p>";
            }
           else{    
            echo "<p id ='left'>
            $display[message]
            </p>";
            }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks.`logged_user` was not in SQL select return.After adding it its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` instead of `==` is converting a comparison to an assignment. Your query needs to be updated to return the user as well. It also should be parameterized.

```
$query = mysqli_prepare($conn, 'select message, logged_user FROM data where 
            (logged_user = ? and name = ?) 
            OR 
            (logged_user = ? and name = ?)');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'ssss', $_SESSION['ID'], $_SESSION['frendid'], $_SESSION['frendid'], $_SESSION['ID']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php for more information.

Also is `name` an id? That doesn't seem like it will ever match up.

Comment: Just little clarification. one equals (=) in PHP is for assignment. so, this variable now contains this value. Two equals (==) means comparison, does variable_one equal variable two. In case anyone reads this and is unsure..